# Plotly.js renders wrong chart when used within a deleted Vue.js component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plotly

### Problem

I got two charts wrapped inside two components. When I delete the first component, the first chart stays.

See jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m4ywp5fc/4/

### Approach

I'm trying to replot the chart using `Plotly.replot` but it seems that Vue.js does something internally which I don't understand. Also `Plotly.purge` does nothing in this case.

### Code

Or see jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m4ywp5fc/4/

#### JavaScript

```
Vue.component('chart-one', {
    props: ['id'],

  template: `<div :id="'chart-' + id"></div>`,

  mounted () {
    const trace = {
      x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
      y: Array.from({length: 4}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 40))
    }

    Plotly.newPlot('chart-' + this.id, [trace])
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: () => ({
    charts: [1, 2]
  }),

  methods: {
    remove () {
        this.charts.splice(0, 1)
    }
  }
})
```

#### HTML

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  Charts: {{ charts }}
  <button @click="remove">
    Delete first chart
  </button>

  <div v-for="(chart, index) in charts">
    <chart-one :id="'chart-' + index"></chart-one>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Additional note

Please notice that my application is much more complex.

Comment: It seems like *part* of your problem is caused by a typo, `:id="'chart-' + index"` You are referring to the array indexes, instead of the value (you should have used `chart` instead). Is this caused by your attempt to minify the code?

Comment: You are absolutely right. But even when changing it to `chart` from `index` it still shows the wrong chart. Yes, I minify the code, but not a development environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by 2 reasons:

## A typo in your demo code

```
<chart-one :id="'chart-' + index"></chart-one>
```

should be

```
<chart-one :id="'chart-' + chart"></chart-one>
```

## Failure to handle changing of props inside your component

Vue, by default assumes that a component automatically updates when its properties are changed, while this is part of the framework itself, your component fails to handle this situation.

This is what happens:

1. Vue first renders with 2 instances of `chart-one`, and the values [1, 2]
2. When you click the button, Vue is asked to re-render with 1 `chart-one` [1]
3. Vue updates the `id` variable on the first component to 2, and then sees it still has 1 unused component remaining, so it nukes it

This can be solved in the following ways:

### Adding a `key` variable:

If you add a [`key`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) to the `chart-one` component, vue can actually do "tracking" of the instances:

```
<chart-one :id="'chart-' + chart" :key="chart"></chart-one>
```

Instead of doing the "update values in the first component" it now intelligently nukes and recreates dom nodes to match the values passed in.

Comment: Oh my god, a simple key I've used so often clears the problem. I'm into the problem for weeks now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Notice than another solution is to make your component properly re render itself when one of its props changes, however, that's a little bit harder to do, and the `key` is also needed in the case you want to add future animations and such

Comment: Good to know. For others reading it: Use `eslint-plugin-vue` and make sure `vue/require-v-for-key` is enabled.